# Как разнообразить математический язык?

Tags: стилистика

При написании математических текстов точность часто входит в противоречие с грамматической правильностью и, особенно, с хорошим стилем. Подбирать синонимы к терминам обычно недопустимо. Тем большее внимание приходится уделять окружающим их словам.
При написании инструкции к проверке задач я "родила" такое предложение:

> Приведенное доказательство использует сведения, не известные ученикам 5-6 класса. Поэтому можно принять приведенное выше решение даже если оно не содержит обоснования.

Корявенько. Два раза "приведенное", да и смысл, кажется, не очень ясен. Может, кто поможет отредактировать это чудовище?

Comment: Кстати, хотите подарю задачку Вместе с копирайтами? Она не совсем математическая, на пространственное мышление. 100% засыпать любого студента.

*Возьмите 5-6 небольших огурцов правильной формы. Один отложите. Остальные разрежьте вдоль точно по осевой. Посмотрите расположение семечек на плоскостях срезов в половинках относительно осевой огурца. Объясните полученные результаты и нарисуйте предполагаемое расположение семечек на поперечном срезе. Для проверки разрежьте последний огурец поперек.*     
  
Ну как? ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Срочно бегу в магазин за огурцами!  

Насколько я помню, у огурцов "тройная" симметрия, т.е. автоморфизмом является поворот вокруг оси на 120о.   

Кстати, задачу лучше задавать мальчикам: девочки с большей вероятностью уже резали огурцы!  ))))

Comment: @behemothus, Вы что, совсем не спите? Ваша деятельность на форуме идет с перерывами максимум 3-4 часа... Поберегите здоровье, Вы нам еще нужны... )))

Comment: >Кстати, задачу лучше задавать мальчикам: девочки с большей вероятностью уже резали огурцы! ))))  
  
Ах, у вас оборудования под рукой нет. )))
Я вам расскажу. На плоскости продольного разреза на одной половине от осевой семечки пости всегда лежат в плоскости разреза, на второй - поперек. Отклонения как правила очень незначительны.
Да, "тройная сиссметирия", но это ещё не объяснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доказательство = решению?
Если да, то просто заменить на "оно". Если нет, то приведенное = изложеннуму, описанному, указанному и т.д.

ЗЫ Никогда бы не подумал, что "приведенное" - термин.

Comment: Нет, конечно, не термин. Доказательство не равно решению (решение состоит из гипотезы и ее обоснования).  
"Изложенному" попробую, спасибо. Просто что-то перемкнуло насчет синонимов...

Comment: >Доказательство не равно решению  
  
Почему бы и нет? Если в задании требуется что-то доказать, то рано.

Comment: Не очень понимаю смысл высказывания, но, может быть, подойдет вариант "предложенное выше решение"

Comment: Тогда уж "изложенное выше". "Предложенное" претендовало бы на некоторый научный приоритет.

Comment: Это зависит от сути описанной ситуации. Если автор предлагает именно такой  способ решения, который для данной аудитории, по её мнению, предпочтительнее - тогда "предложенный". Если дает как один из вариантов, то "изложенный". (Если, конечно, я верно представляю эту ситуацию)

Comment: А что тут в ситуации непонятного? Автор ничего не предлагает. 
Есть задача, из учебника или олимпиадная. Для 5-6 классов. Есть "правильное" (по мнению автора) решение, состоящее из идеи (гипотезы) и её доказательства. Доказательство требует знаний, выходящих за рамки школьной программы этих классов. Решающий дает решение без строгого доказательства. Вопрос, засчитывать ли такое решение. 
Ладно, подождем "автора".

Comment: Согласна с @behemothus. Поменяла первое слово на "Изложенное". Я готовлю олимпиаду для учителей, где среди прочих "методические" задачи. То есть суть не только в том, чтобы решить, а в том, чтобы правильно проверить решение, найти ошибки, оценить. Вот я и предлагаю в "ответе" полное решение (догадка + доказательство), но указываю, что требовать такого доказательство с учеников не надо, хорошо, если они хотя бы приведут правильную догадку.  

Может, так и написать, без канцелярщины?